# Personalizar tela de um plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Olá, minha dúvida é a seguinte, criei um plugin que gera um custom post type, e uma taxonomia para este tipo de post e uns custom fields usando o plugin metabox, no meu caso, para gerenciar os clientes do meu site, tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas na lista dos clientes no admin, as colunas que são exibidas são limitadas, aparecem só os nomes do cliente e data de cadastro, gostaria de personalizar estas colunas, adicionando outros campos. Outra dúvida é como alterar a ordem dos dados, se seria possivel alterar o "order_by" desta lista.

agradeço desde já !

Comment: Não está nada claro qual o seu problema, tem a ver com isto? [Showing user ID on user main page from screen options](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/101322/12615) ou [How can I add a cell in users display table in wordpress admin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8563103/1287812)

Comment: Então, resolveu o problema?